# What do all of the "extra flags" variables stand for?

Tags: makefile, compilation, cross-compiling, configure

When compiling, and specifically at the `./configure` stage, remembering that `--extra-cflags` stands for extra compiler allows me to remember that option helps me pass extra options to the compiler I'm using. I understand that options like these reference variables that are set in the MAKE file?, but I don't understand what the rest of them stand for.

For example, I know that `--extra-ldflags` passes extra flags to the linker, but I'm not sure what that extra *d* is doing there. The help for the configure that I am looking at also lists `--extra-ldexeflags` and `--extra-ldsoflags`. Searching provides information on what some of the above options do, but nothing on what they actually stand for, which is a crucial step for me in being able to recall what they do.

Comment: `ld`: LoaDer or Link eDitor. `so`: Shared Object. `exe`: EXEcutable. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I suppose so, but with sources, and some history on where they came from. In particular,  when was it decided that `ld` would alternately LoaDer or Link eDitor. Both of these seem very particular, deliberate decisions made by someone at some point, but I can find no information on the who or when.